# How to apply contains to list in django?

Tags: django, filter, model, django-queryset

I want to search for filtered objects.

Below is the filtered object.

```
questions = models.Question.objects.filter(creator=user, tags__name__in=hashtags)
```

and I tried the following command. But it does not work.

```
questions = models.Question.objects.filter(tags__name__contains=hashtags)
```

I think, __contains does not seem to work on the list

p.s. hashtags is a list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object for this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

for tag in hashtags:
    conditions |= Q(tags__name__contains=tag)
questions = models.Question.objects.filter(conditions)
```